# No Safari Extension Certificate

Tags: safari, safari-extension, extension-builder3

My Extension Builder cannot detect my safari extension certificate.
I have followed all the steps properly like

```
1.Generate a new certificate (I have enrolled in the program)
2.open keychain access
3.drop certificate at system > certificates
4.double click certificate and make it trust all
```

My MAC os (OS X EI Captain, 10.11.6) and safari are latest version.
still my extension builder says "No Safari Extension Certificate"

**Please do not mark it duplicate** as I have gone through every link I found related to it but there is nothing useful.an I posted this Question when I really freaked out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Mistake, I was selecting IOS instead of safari , while generating certificate.

just in case if somebody runs into the same Issue:
when you reach **certificates, identifiers & Profiles** select **Safari Extensions** in the drop-down at the left of tye screen, if you already have a certificate available, you need to click on + sign at right of the screen, they will show you the Guide automatically

Comment: Apple shouldn't have hidden the safari extensions certificates in that drop-down box...

Comment: can you help me out of this i am not getting this option for safari Extension certificate